# bit default value set to ((0)) but looking in design view show dbo.tablename_columnname_D

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Just wondering why it does this on SQL2008R2, may have on earlier ones. I assume SQL is naming the default value but why it doesn't just leave it as 0? I notice if I script as create it sets the default value in the script if it is ((0)) but not when it's dbo.tablename_columnname_D. Could have something to do with having multiple databases with the same tables and structure?

Comment: I have no idea what your question means. I think you're asking about how or why SQL Server [generates constraint names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx) if you don't specify one yourself, but I'm really not sure. I suggest you show some code from your script to make your question clearer.

Comment: I guess if you've never run across this, then yea it would be hard to understand what I'm trying to say. I was losing my default value when copying a table. I understand why but looking at the table column in design view the default value is suppose to be ((0)). But instead of the zero I see dbo.ARTransactions_NSFCheck_D....just wondering if anyone knows why. It seems to work in production but not when I script table as create to.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean. What is "copying a table": how are you copying it? And where do see the text instead of the zero? Then you mention scripting a table, but you just said it's "not working" which isn't really clear either. Instead of describing your problem, please show it clearly by posting a script showing the (presumably) incorrect code, and/or a screenshot showing the incorrect text. And I would [avoid the visual tools](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers) if possible and work only with scripts.

Comment: I can't post what I see in design view of the table. Forget about the scripting as create to. In the design view instead of having ((0)) as it shows up when you set it's default to zero it has the dbo.ARTransactions_NSFCheck_D. I'm just saying scripting the table out is where this causes problems as it just doesn't set a default value at all.